beginner repairing trim on staircase
Bought the house a year ago and whoever did the trim on our stairs did a very bad job. I've never messed with trim before so I have some questions. I have all the trim pieces, but if you breathe on them they fall off.
Do I need a nail gun?
Do I need to repair the gaps before I re-secure the trim?
Do I need to use some kind of screws for the bit at the top of the stairs?
Is there an online resource with a walk-through for a job like this?
Thanks in advance from a clueless beginner.



I don't see any nail holes...

Nobody needs a nailgun, but they are very nice to have if you do a lot nailing.  Replacing a bit of trim does not really count.
Trim is used to hide small gaps.  That is its main use besides looking nice.
You use finishing(tiny heads) nails for trim.  Quite often, trim that is falling off, the nails only went into drywall.  Either because of missing the wood behind, or too short.
1/2 inch thick trim plus 1/2 inch drywall requires 1.5 or more long nails.

OTOH... this is an excellent excuse to buy a nail gun. For this task, they might be better off getting a brad nailer.

@gnicko   You must at least hit you thumb once with a hammer before calling yourself a handyman.  Then you get a nailgun.
